# Grub2 fails to install on Asus A315-31-C8WK

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I had 17.10 installed previously and I believe someone messed with my laptop both uninstalling Ubuntu and grub2. Now that im trying to reinstall I can't get grub2 to install, it was a hassle the first time and I can't get it to work now. It's a low end Asus laptop model A315-31-C8WK any help is appreciated. I'm not totally new to Ubuntu, but it's been a couple of months since I've last used it for the same reason.

Comment: What is your exact problem? I mean, when I installed Ubuntu, I didn't even notice `grub` was installed along with it. It was just _there_. Do you have (or want) dual-boot?

Comment: Not trying to dual boot. During the installation process, it doesnt freeze as I can do other things, but the installer stops progress once it starts trying to install grub.